# Some posts not visible on the feed through Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I'm working on an application that uses page's feed. Recently I've noticed that some posts from the feed are not visible through Graph API (and FQL, too), but are still visible on the regular page under "Recent posts by others".

Here's an example: http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=539919279372939&id=77702235732 . If you open this URL, you should see the post, but Graph API explorer doesn't: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=77702235732_539919279372939 . What's going on? Is it a matter of some special privacy settings on the author's side, or is it Facebook's bug?

Comment: It is not a facebook Bug. It is all about settings on the owner's part.

Comment: Do you know which setting exactly? It's not about seeing friend's post - I've created a new account (so I have 0 friends on it) and it still can see the post Graph API can't.

Comment: There is a way for users to block app access to your profile, somewhere in your settings. Facebook has changed this since the last time I checked. If the setting is enabled, no app can access the user's data.